# Why does Python allow abstract methods to have code?

Tags: python, abstract

Why does python allow one to have code inside an abstract method? I know we can invoke that code through super, but I am not able to think of reasons why would I want my abstract method to have code in it.

Comment: To provide standard infrastructure? Python is a language for consulting adults, it doesn't *restrict* you from extending the model.

Comment: Abstract base classes are a *tool*, after all, not a constraining device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in the [`abc` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod):

> Note: Unlike Java abstract methods, these abstract methods may have an implementation. This implementation can be called via the `super()` mechanism from the class that overrides it. **This could be useful as an end-point for a super-call in a framework that uses cooperative multiple-inheritance.**

(Emphasis added.)

It's also explained in the PEP that introduced ABCs, and you can follow links from the PEP to python-dev and -ideas threads that discussed the decision in more detail. (That's one of the advantages of a language being developed out in the wide-open; for anything added after about 2.2, you don't have to wonder about questions like this, you can just look up the whole discussion.)